# Gmail Server not accescepting mails form sendmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, amazon-web-services, sendmail

I am tring to send email using sendmail app via aws SES system. The outlook server easly accepts the email request but gmail server dosen't. can someone help me with wrong in this. Thnakyou.

here are logs

logs for gmail

```
Oct 30 05:38:06 v*******5 sm-mta[19968]: 39U5c6nN019966: to=<*****@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120977, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:4023:1002::1a], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
        
Oct 30 05:38:06 v*******5 sm-mta[19968]: 39U5c6nN019966: 39U5c6nN019968: DSN: Service unavailable

Oct 30 05:38:07 v*******5 sm-mta[19968]: 39U5c6nN019968: to=<noreply@cdl-lb-*******.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=cdl-lb-*******....elb.amazonaws.com. [34.234.182.53], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by cdl-lb-********.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

logs for outlook

```
Oct 30 05:37:00 v*******5 sm-mta[19873]: 39U5aurD019871: to=<******@nexsales.com>, delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=120978, relay=n****-com.mail....ction.outlook.com. [52.101.132.30], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<6******@*****k.com> [InternalId=114993454396419, Hostname=KL1PR0401MB4340.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com] 10024 bytes in 0.301, 32.520 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like you're using AWS SES, though? If you were using AWS SES, your sendmail wouldn't be talking to Gmail directly... it'd be talking to SES.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1814657/edit) any additional information in your question rather than in a comment, which may get deleted

Comment: i have updated the question